# How to generate random password for customer in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, password

We had a method to generate the random passwords for the customers in Magento1 in following class.

```
app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php
```

method >>

```
 /**
     * Retrieve random password
     *
     * @param   int $length
     * @return  string
     */
    public function generatePassword($length = 8)
    {
        $chars = Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_LOWERS
            . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_UPPERS
            . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_DIGITS
            . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_SPECIALS;
        return Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length, $chars);
    }
```

What is the similar method in Magento2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following code to generate the passwords for the customers.

```
<?php
namespace Muk\Common\Helper;

class CustomerPasswordGeneration extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Math\Random
     */
    protected $mathRandom;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom
    ) {        
        $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve random password
     *
     * @param   int $length
     * @return  string
     */
    public function generatePassword($length = 10)
    {
        $chars = \Magento\Framework\Math\Random::CHARS_LOWERS
            . \Magento\Framework\Math\Random::CHARS_UPPERS
            . \Magento\Framework\Math\Random::CHARS_DIGITS;

        return $password = $this->mathRandom->getRandomString($length, $chars);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento use function like this in the setup script

vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php

```
 /**
     * Generate password string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function generatePassword()
    {
        return $this->encryptor->getHash($this->data[self::KEY_PASSWORD], true);
    }
```

Comment: I know about this. But in my case I am not passing self::KEY_PASSWORD to generate the password.

Comment: also check Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php 
I think you have to generate password string by your own if you have not it

Comment: yes, for random strings I can use class Magento\Framework\Math\Random

Answer (score 1):

I have made one custom url (new custom controller) to generate customer's password .

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface as Encryptor;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_indexer;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,Encryptor $encryptor, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $password = '123456'; //or you can use php random function rand() to generate string
        $hash = $this->encryptor->hash($password);
        $newhash = $this->encryptor->getHash($password, true);
        echo $newhash; // this will be customer's new password, which need to store in 'password_hash' column of "customer_entity" db table.
    }
}
```

you can integrate same code in your functional method / file .

Answer (score 0):

I used this code simply and got result

```
  <?php 
   function generateRandomString($length) {
        $characters = 
       '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$%&';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
?>

<?php echo generateRandomString(5);  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method

```
    <?php

 function randomPassword()
        {
            $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
            $password = [];
            $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
                $password[] = $alphabet[$n];
            }
            return implode($password);
        }

randomPassword();
```